# How to get customized Joomla menu along with sub-menu

Tags: joomla, menu, joomla3.0, submenu, joomla-module

I want add schema in my Joomla menu...! Below is code

```
<?php
        $menu = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu();
        // Get menu items - array with menu items
        $items = $menu->getItems('menutype', 'mainmenu');
        //print_r($items);
        ?>
        <ul itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
            <?php foreach($items as $i => $menu_item){

                ?>
                <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.10leaves.ae/"><?php if($menu_item->level == '1') { echo $menu_item->title; } ?></a>
                    <?php if($menu_item->level == '2') {?>
                    <ul>
                        <li><?php echo $menu_item->title; ?></li>
                    </ul><?php } ?>
                </li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
```

problem I am facing is, above not printing sub-menu I could not find any solution

For Example :

```
<ul itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
                            <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.10leaves.ae/">Home</a>
                </li>
                            <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.10leaves.ae/">DIFC</a>
                </li>
                            <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.10leaves.ae/">ADGM</a>
                </li>
                            <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.10leaves.ae/">About</a>
                </li>
                            <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.10leaves.ae/">Publications</a>
                </li>
                            <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.10leaves.ae/">FinTech: Now Everybody Wants A Slice of the Pie</a>
                </li>
                            <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.10leaves.ae/">The Role of Financial Centres in Emerging Economies</a>
                </li>
                            <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.10leaves.ae/">Bitcoin versus Ethereum </a>
                </li>
                            <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.10leaves.ae/">ADGM</a>
                </li>
                            <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.10leaves.ae/">DIFC</a>
                </li>
                            <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.10leaves.ae/">Finance</a>
                </li>
                            <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.10leaves.ae/">Contact</a>
                </li>
                    </ul>
```

Publication Menu has submenu (FinTech) and two more. I cannot figure it out how to make them print in Submenu

Comment: When you have Joomla-specific issues/questions in the future please post them at Joomla Stack Exchange to reach a dedicated audience for support.  Team Joomla _wants_ you to post there, that's why in the administrator -> Help menu, the 2nd last item in the dropdown is **Stack Exchange**. That link takes you to JSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not try this [Extension](https://www.tassos.gr/joomla-extensions/google-structured-data-markup/docs/the-menu-manager-integration) from Tassos Marinos

Dave

Comment: This link-only answer is low-value because links die.  Please put more permanent details in this answer.  If you are able to solve Joomla-centric issues, please create a Joomla Stacke Exchange account and share your expertise with the community that is dedicated to serving Joomla.  ...where are you from Dave? wanna add a location to your profile?